# Git stash untracked files doesn't work in Visual Studio Developer Powershell?

Tags: git, visual-studio, powershell, git-stash

I tried several times to git stash my untracked filed in Developer Powershell without success.

```
C:\dir\dir2\Myrepo [develop ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> git stash -u
fatal: unknown subcommand: –u

usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<options>] [<stash>]
   or: git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash clear
   or: git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                 [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
                 [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]]
                 [--] [<pathspec>...]]
   or: git stash save [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                 [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]

C:\dir\dir2\Myrepo [develop ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> git stash --include-untracked
fatal: unknown subcommand: –-include-untracked

usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<options>] [<stash>]
   or: git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git stash clear
   or: git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                 [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
                 [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]]
                 [--] [<pathspec>...]]
   or: git stash save [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                 [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]
```

I was then able to run a `git stash -u` in a normal Powershell window with no problems.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: Look at the syntax again - `--include-untracked` is only a valid option with `git stash push` or `git stash save`

Comment: I suspect that instead of `-u` you typed, e.g., `–u` or `—u` (en-dash and em-dash before the `u`) or that whatever shell you were using made this kind of substitution. These characters are visually identical in many fonts, but are not the same Unicode code-point.  @MathiasR.Jessen: without a more specific command, `git stash` assumes `push` (in modern Git; `save` in old Git that lacks `push`).